# example of multiplication of ordinals with infinite cardinality with larger value on right where we dont' take the max?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I recall reading about a rule for multiplying ordinals where at 
least one  is infinite, and where the cardinality of the  multiplier (on right) is larger than the multiplicand (on left).

If I recall correctly it says that the result is the MAX of the two.

For example:  $\omega *  \omega ^2 = \omega^2$

However, I also recall reading that there are some exception cases wherein
you can't just take the MAX.   Am I remembering correctly... and if so, 
could I ask one of you nice folks for an example?    Thanks in advance! -chris

Comment: If you’re talking about *ordinal* arithmetic, $\omega$ and $\omega^2$ have the same cardinality, both being countably infinite, and their product is $\omega^3$.

Comment: I guess I got confused with what happens when the multiplicand is finite.  In that case it seems the larger infinite multiplicand will 'absorb' the multiplier.  As in when  we have:  $2 *  \omega = \omega$.   Do I have it right now?  Thanks again!

Comment: That will happen if the second factor is a limit ordinal, but not otherwise. For instance, $2\cdot(\omega+1)=\omega+2$.

Comment: Also note that while $2\cdot\omega=\omega$ you have $\omega\cdot 2\neq\omega$ rather $\omega\cdot 2=\omega+\omega$ (or really $\omega\cdot 2$ is the way you would write it I just expanded to addition to give a better idea of what the order looks like).

Comment: *Cardinal* arithmetic has addition and multiplication with an infinite cardinal reduce to max. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic (There the only case you have to watch out for is multiplication by $0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ordinal arithmetic $w(w+1)=w^2+w>w+1$ . Also $(w_1)*(w_1+w)=(w_1)^2 + w_1w>w_1+w$.